# can somebody explain why $\frac m{s^2}$ is the same as $ms^{-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm looking for the mathematical explanation of why $\frac m{s^2}$ is the same as $ms^{-2}$.

Is it to do with index laws?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the relationship of powers : $$x^2 = x \cdot x \\ x^1 = x \\ x^0 = 1 \\ x^{-1}=\frac{1}{x} \\ x^{-2} = \frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x \cdot x}$$ So $s^{-2} = \frac{1}{s^2}$, which means $ms^{-2}=\frac{m}{s^2}$

Comment: Thank you very much, i suspected it was this but couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 1):

Negative exponents are essentially just a shorthand notation.  I'm assuming you're familiar with this rule of exponents:
$$ \frac{s^a}{s^b} = s^{a-b} $$

Specifically, if $a = 0$ then we have
$$ \frac{s^0}{s^b} = s^{0-b} = s^{-b},$$
but note also that $s^0 = 1$ (as long as $s \ne 0$).  Therefore we see that
$$ \frac{1}{s^b} = s^{-b}.$$

Multiply both sides by $m$ and let $b = 2$ to get the equality you specifically asked about.

Comment: Thank you for this, I suspected this was the case but my mind was not having it.

Comment: No problem.  I know the feeling.